# AngularJS - ng-if checking for true values when key is unknown

Tags: angularjs

I want to apply a `ng-if` in AngularJS depending if any of the values in a JSON is `true`. 
The first level keys are always the same, but then the second level keys are always different. (so I cannot do `ng-if="known_stuff.unpredictable_thing"`, as the name of `"unpredictable_thing"` will be different each time. Here is the JSON.

```
{
    "known_stuff":
        {
            "unpredictable_thing":false
        },
    "known_stuff_2":
        {
            "non_predictable_stuff":true
        },
    "known_stuff_3":
        {
            "something_unknown":false
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know yourself what key to check? Is it only one key in each object?

Comment: It can be more than one, I just want to check if there is any 2nd level key with a true value there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controller:

```
$scope.check = function(someObject) {
    // return true if some value is true inside the object
    for (var key in someObject) {
        if (someObject[key] === true) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

template:

```
ng-if="check(known_stuff)"
```

or

```
ng-show="check(known_stuff)"
```

if your data is an array then the function has to look like that:

```
$scope.checkData = function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var key1 in data[i]) {
            // return true if some value is true inside the object
            for (var key in data[i][key1]) {
                if (data[i][key1][key] === true) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

template:

```
ng-if="checkData(data)"
```

Comment: I would need to check the whole object, not just one of the keys. See plunkr for detail: http://plnkr.co/edit/E84nspKnrAywrvkNYjx1?p=preview

Comment: Your `data` is actually an array in your code and i can not see what you do with this array. Can you extend your example template with the code of what you want to do with this data array?

Comment: I just want to check if there is any true element in $scope.data in order to show/hide an element `<h1>Unique header: </h1`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check any of the value in your provided json is true then

```
ng-if="known_stuff.unpredictable_thing == ture || 
        known_stuff_2.non_predictable_stuff == true ||
        known_stuff_3.something_unknown == true"
```

Comment: The point is that I don't know the second key in advance, so the JSON can be "known_stuff.something_red". I want to know how to check if any value inside is true without knowing the second key.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, your json will have the first level key same (`known_stuff`) but inside `know_stuff` there can be multiple key with different names (like `unpredictable_thing` here).

The easiest solution is to iterate the first level key, gaining key value pair like below.

```
<div ng-repeat = "(key, val) in known_stuff" ng-if="known_stuff[key]">
    //do something --> {{key}} - {{val}}
</div>
```

Supporting Plunk -> http://plnkr.co/edit/6hQQAtqRseb1gWvueFKr

-----------------------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------------------

Assign jsonData with your data.

```
<div ng-repeat= "stuff in jsonData">
  <div ng-repeat = "(key, val) in stuff" ng-if="stuff[key]">
      //do something --> {{key}} - {{val}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, updated the same plunk. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: The point is that this would work if I have just 1 first level key, but I have 3 of them (known_stuff, known_stuff_2, known_stuff_3)

Comment: Nest this call with ng-repeat for first layer as well. It'll work.  I'll just update the code & corresponding plunk for reference.

Comment: The point is that I want to show/hide a unique element depending if there is a true key or not. With your approach this element is repeated if two of the first level keys have a second level key with a true value. You can check the forked plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ORF94TCeAsUZW7D2fWZm?p=preview